# Disabling the ActionBar leads to App crash

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

If I disable the ActionBar in my Android App by simply changing the styles.xml (themes.xml in my case) to:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="JARVISAPP" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/teal_200</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

... the App crashes instantly on startup because somehow it wants to run the setTitle() method on the ActionBar that doesn't exist anymore. If I use the standard DarkActionBar, everything works just fine.

Edit: Here's the errors Android Studio is printing:
[image: errors]

Comment: Open Logcat at the bottom of the screen and attack a screenshot of any red text. This is what the error is and can help people understand your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing MainActivity to extend android.app.Activity instead of AppCompatActivity because the latter requires that your activity's/app's theme inherits one of the action bar themes, or try adding

```
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
```

to the theme used by MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

> `<style name="JARVISAPP" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`

Your app's style inherits from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`, and hence your have won't have an ActionBar.

And therefore when you call `getSupportActionBar()` will be `null`

So, you got NullPointerException when calling `getSupportActionBar().getTitle()`

So either don't set a title to actionBar or make your app's theme inherit from a theme that has an action bar like below one

`<style name="JARVISAPP" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`